# Hide certain inputs and show others using a switch button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

Hello Stackoverflow community, hope that you're doing well, what I'm trying to do is when I click the switch button I want it to hide certain inputs and show others, my code is a form to add students and teachers, since there are cummon inputs I tought about hide the uncummon one when I press the switch button and when I click it again do the opposite but all of that seem to be failed, I can only hide some and when I click it again it won't work, here what I did:

**The Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.teacher').hide();
    $('.switch').click(function(){
        $('.student').hide();
        $('.teacher').show();
    });
});
```

**The HTML code:**

```
 <label>Student&nbsp;</label>
                                    <label class="switch">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="switchVal" value="0">
                                      <span class="slider"></span>
                                    </label> 
                                    <label>&nbsp;Teacher</label>
```

Comment: PS: don't just use `<label>Student&nbsp;</label>` for the sake of having some `<label>` tag. That's invalid. A label should wrap an action Input element or point to its ID using the `for` attribute.

Comment: aaah I get it thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.teacher').hide();
  $('.switch').click(function() {
    $('.student').toggle();
    $('.teacher').toggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='student'>Student</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switchVal" value="0">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</div>
<div class='teacher'>Teacher</div>
```

Comment: It worked thank you, thanks to you know I know what is a toggle button

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".teacher, .student").toggle();`
Or, if needed, for more granular control you could always get the current checkbox state using

```js
const isChecked = this.checked; // boolean`
```

Example:

```js
jQuery($ => {

  $(".teacher").hide();
  
  $("#switchVal").on("input", function() {
    $(".teacher, .student").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.toggler {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggler-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
}
.toggler-checkbox::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #0bf;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.toggler input:checked ~ .toggler-checkbox::before {
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
.toggler-label {
  user-select: none;
}
.toggler-label:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: -1;
  color: #0bf;
}
.toggler input:checked ~ .toggler-label:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: inherit;
}
.toggler input:checked ~ .toggler-label:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #0bf;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switchVal" value="0" hidden>
  <span class="toggler-checkbox"></span>
  <b class="toggler-label">Student</b>
  <b class="toggler-label">Teacher</b>
</label>

<ul>
  <li class="student">Student: Anna</li>
  <li class="student">Student: John</li>
  <li class="teacher">Teacher: Mark</li>
  <li class="student">Student: Tara</li>
  <li class="teacher">Teacher: Zack</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```